# C#, Web Form, and Visual Studio: How to convert from Windows Forms to ASP.Net Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, web-applications

I am a beginner so please bear with me.

I created a dummy windows form to test out some code. It basically has 5 text boxes and a button that saves the text into an array of objects with fields that contain that information. I then display it onto a rich Text Box.

I am working in a group and I am tasked to deal with the back end of a Asp.Net app, while the others handle the layout by placing text boxes and buttons where they deem fit.

I am trying to translate this code into an ASP.NET version. **I really just need to know the ASP.NET equivalent of button event handlers(button_click) so I know where to call the method, textbox.Text so I can change the code from textbox.text to its ASP.NET counterpart, and anything else that needs to change to make that app work such as directives.**

I simplified the code so that each event handler should only need to call an applicable method.

Comment: The handlers and properties are nearly identical. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net web form the button will be like

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSomeButton" OnClick="btnSomeButton_Click" Text="Login" />
```

And the C# code for handling this event will be like

```
protected void btnSomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

In that function you can use commands like textbox.Text

Comment: Thank you for responding,

\nsay I had some method that displays to a textbox when the button is clicked, example Display(), where would that go on the ASP.NET version?

\n-EDIT: I reread your comment and I am now understanding that the event   handler for the ASP.NET button already exists somewhere within the app's files?

Comment: You can call the Display() function in that button's click method

Comment: No there are two files in Web Forms one is generally .aspx. and shows what the Web Form will look like, the other is C# file and is attached to aspx file. The C# file contains all the code. You will have to make the event handler for the buttons (or just double click the button in Web Form design)

Answer (score 0):

Kevin, there are essentially two ways to do that. You can either use visual studio’s HTML designer to create the event for you or you can do it manually from the code behind.

This is how you do it using the designer:

You can essentially drag and drop a new Button control into the designer and override its OnClick event (It will show up in the properties window in VS once you select the control). VS will then add the event to the code behind (it is the .cs file that is associated with the .aspx). You’ll end up with something like this:

(in .aspx page)

```
<asp:Button ID="TestBtn" runat="server" OnClick="Button_Clicked" Text="Click Me" />
```

(Overriding the OnClick event in the designer will create the following method in the .cs file)

```
 protected void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //Do something here 
    //Display();
 }
```

You can essentially do the same thing programmatically by dragging and drop the Button control into the designer (same as before). The difference is that you will override its OnClick event from the code behind instead of the designer.

(in .aspx page)

```
<asp:Button ID="TestBtn" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
```

(in .cs file)

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        TestBtn.Click += TestBtn_Click;
    }           
}
void TestBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do things here
    //Do Something()
}
```

Keep in mind that the second method is preferred, but's really up to you and your team.

Here are some good documentations from MSDN if you want to know more about webform's events and page life cycles

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx